# AngularJS catch login exception

Tags: angularjs, authentication, jax-rs

I have developed admin app with **AngularJS** and **JAVA** as server side **Restfull API**, I want now that if the user tape a wrong login/password couple , I want to handle the error and show a message in the client side page , here is my code:

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("auth")
public class LoginResource {

    @Inject
    private UserServiceLocal userServiceLocal;

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response authenticate(Credentials credentials) {

        User userLoggedIn = userServiceLocal.authenticate(
                credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword());
        if (userLoggedIn != null) {
            userServiceLocal.setToken(userLoggedIn, TokenUtils.createToken());
            return Response.ok(userLoggedIn).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my client side code :

```
function login(username, password) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http
        .post(auth_uri, {
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        .then(
            function(response) {
                if(response){   

                    userInfo = {
                      accessToken: response.data.token
                    };
                    $window.sessionStorage["token"] = response.data.token;
                    $rootScope.token = response.data.token;
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }
            }, 
            function(error) {
                  deferred.reject(error);                      
            });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

and here when I consume the login service :

```
function LoginController($scope, $state, authenticationSvc){
    $scope.submit = function(credentials) {

        authenticationSvc
            .login(credentials.username, credentials.password)
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    $state.go('dashboard.home');
                    console.log(response.status);

                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('error.status : ' + error.status)
                });         
    }
};
```

the problem is when I try to issue an error to test the error response, I have the error showed on the console of the browser, but not caught in the error `callbackof` the promise, what is wrong please ?

Comment: `error` is null OR `error.status` is null

because [error](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) is often a `String` litteral. I said OFTEN not ALWAYS nor MUST

Comment: $http.post already returns a promise, no need to use `$q` here

Comment: @SalathielGenèse , but in the API , if there are an error in the login method , I return : Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build()

Comment: Let me tell you the truth. I'm an "`expert`" in java but only SE. So I do not really get what that J2E class is doing, yet, and concerning only JS, I see you writing `if (response)` why?

Comment: As if the authentication can succeed, yet the response header be `200 OK` instead of `401 UNAUTHORIZED` see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes). I'm ALMOST sure the promise is either `faithful` or `faithless` according to the response header

Comment: @SalathielGenèse , thanks for your attention, I wrote this test because I can have a case that the response is undefined and no error object !

Comment: [majd hwas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4464786/majd-hwas) please issue an answer on how you have solved it

Comment: I also wonder, though I've many languages in few day, J2E seem bizarre to me. Not that the syntax is difficult but need, according to me, too much work to bootstrap. Which book(s)/resources could you recommend to me [salathielgenese@gmail.com](mailto:salathielgenese@gmail.com)

Comment: I am ok with you that j2e seem very complicated , and the documentations are also rare and hard to understand , but this is why it is a very usefull technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the return statement in your $http callbacks. Or as suggested in comment you can just return the result of $http to simplify (it is already a promise).

```
...function(error) { return deferred.reject(error);});
```

Comment: is insufficient to return deferred.promise in finally ?

Comment: no it is not. The inner callback need to return the promise with its result. The  final promise just return the promise attached to the deferred for you to be able to call the 'then' method in you login controller.

Comment: Would try this for the login function: `return $http.post(auth_uri, {
            username: username,
            password: password
          })
          .then(
              function(response) {
                    userInfo = {
                      accessToken: response.data.token
                    };
                    $window.sessionStorage["token"] = response.data.token;
                    $rootScope.token = response.data.token;
                    return response;
              });`